# PyCharm with Pyenv

Tags: python, pycharm

How to use Pyenv virtualenv's with Pycharm 2016.3? In the earlier version of Pycharm, I could easily set up local interpreter to point anything installed on my machine.

My first idea was to add `.python-version` file on the root of the project. I Pyenv virtualenv installed so this will activate & run the project with correct environment automatically. However, Pycharm still doesn't see the correct interpreter causing it to though import and syntax errors.

How can I select my local Pyenv in new PyCharm 2016.3 I used to be able to set the path as variable now I can only browse the path using drop-down menu. It doesn't seem to show hidden files like default path for pyenv `~./.pyenv/versions{project}`.

Comment: Using a single Python interpreter is still easy to specify (see below), but how do I specify all interpreters (i.e. all of which are listed by `pyenv global`)? I need this to test against several versions when I use [Tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This would require to somewhat run `source <(pyenv init -)` or similar, [according to the docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation), in the shell that runs `tox`.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

In Pycharm version 2017.3, you can go to 
**Pycharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> `<`project_name`>` -> settings button on the right of the python interpreter text box -> Add local**

This will open a new window with virtualenv Environment as one of the options on the left. On Selecting it, you will get an option to make a new virtualenv environment or use an existing virtual environment. Here next to the dropdown text box, you can click "..." and browse to your existing virtualenv created using pyenv and select it. It will select this virtualenv when you start terminal from Pycharm and also use the corresponding python interpreter as set while creating that virtualenv.

[image]

Comment: Just accepted your answer as its better than the existing one.

Comment: A suggestion for improvement is to use a pyenv python version not as a virtual environment, but rather as a *base interpreter* for a new one. 
This would let you create multiple virtual environments per python version.

Comment: @EliadL, you can achieve that simply browsing to the .pyenv directory and selecting the relevant `/bin/python` when you select the base interpreter.

Comment: @Def_Os How is that different from my suggestion?

Comment: @EliadL, I thought you were under the impression that it is not currently possible, hence my instructions.

Answer (score 26):

Get [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) plugin for more project-specialized environments.

Then, create a new environment for project: (assume that we installed *python-3.7.1* with *pyenv* and we'll use it)

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.7.1 projectName-3.7.1
```

This command generates folder for our environment.

Open `pyCharm` (*v2018.3.1 used*):

**Create New Project** > **Existing Interpreter**

Now you can type path of your environment:

```
~/.pyenv/versions/projectName-3.7.1/bin/python3
```

Then press **Create**..
That's all.

If there is already exists project:

**File** > **Settings** > **Project: projectName** > **Project: Interpreter**

Again, you can type *path* of the environment as like above. So you will see packages installed on this environment.

If you want to use same version of python and environment on the command line, then you must activate the environment with

```
$ pyenv activate projectName-3.7.1
```

command.

Note that `pyenv virtualenv` [can activate that environment when entering the folder within the terminal](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv) through putting the name of it into your `.python-version` file as well.

For more command about `pyenv-virtualenv` you can look for reference sheet.

Comment: This is still not enough due to problems pyenv creates which messes up $PATH https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/274

Comment: This answer in combination with the information from the accepted one was very helpful for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I made the best experiences with using `pyenv` and `pipenv` together. So far, I used separate commands for that, rather than using the `pyenv-virtualenv` plugin, but it should be supported with this hint as well.

My workflow to start a new project:

1. Create folder and switch into it:
   `mkdir new_project ; cd new_project`
2. Set desired local pyenv version:
   `pyenv local 3.8.0`
3. Create an empty `pipenv` virtual environment, using just that local version:
   `pipenv --python $(pyenv which python)`

Now comes the tricky part: PyCharm is supporting Pipenv as an interpreter, but it doesn't recognize it automatically anymore after the initial interpreter selection (which happens at project initiation / first time opening of the project, automatically).
So - if you just created the new project folder (without PyCharm's `.idea/` folder created yet), it will recognize the Pipenv-Virtualenv of the project just fine and set it as a project interpreter, automatically:

[image: new project interpreter]

If there is already an `.idea/` folder, it's not that easy, since PyCharm's GUI just supports to create a new Pipenv environment, but you still have an option:

1. Close PyCharm, delete `.idea/` folder and reopen the project folder in PyCharm.

   - This will delete other project settings as well, but shouldn't be something too important for a fresh environment.
2. Open the folder in PyCharm again and it will recognize your Pipenv virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  I was able to figure out how to coerce the introduction of a `pyenv` _shim_ into an existing PyCharm project w/o blowing away the `.idea` directory. My addition is in an answer somewhere on this page.

Comment: This works for me. I am using PyCharm 2022.2.1 and python 3.10.7 using pyenv and venv. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

After taking a lead from Mr. Judge regarding the use of `pyenv`,  I stumbled on a way to introduce an interpreter from `pyenv` to an *existing* PyCharm (2020.2.2, if it matters) project without blowing away the `.idea` directory.

Prior to using any other Environment type (Pipenv, Poetry, etc.), first open the `Virtual Environment` option:
[image: Add Python Interpreter Dialog]
Select `Exiting environment` and then navigate to one of your `pyenv` *shims* using the […] button to the right of the `Interpreter:` drop-down. Then click `Make available to all projects`.

You can then go to the Pipenv or Poetry Environemnt (Plugin) to reference that introduced interpreter now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. Do you mean `pipenv` at the begining and not `pyenv`? Also, I don't get why the "shimmed python" is made available as a virtualenv while it is more like a "system interpreter" rather than a virtualenv.

Comment: That `---` in the interpreter path really threw me off. I finally realized all you have to do is `which python` in terminal, then browse to that version of python in the above PyCharm dialogue. On macOS for me it's `/Users/[redacted-username]/.pyenv/shims/python`. Specifying `python3` for some reason didn't work (PyCharm said `Invalid Interpreter`, but with pyenv, `python` ended up being the same pyenv shim as `python3`, so it didn't matter.)

Comment: I set `/Users/myName/.pyenv/shims/Python`  as a Python interpretor. When I switch the version with `global` command it does change instantly when I run `Python -V` but pyCharm selects a versioned path instead of `/Users/AdnanAhmad/.pyenv/shims/Python`. Why is that?

Answer (score 5):

You don’t mention what operating system you’re using, and it’s relevant here.

If it’s OS X or macOS, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in the file selection dialog (when you’re choosing the location of a new local interpreter) to enter a path manually.  (This is a standard macOS shortcut that works in any native file selection dialog.)

Comment: Thanks I'm in Mac os

Comment: The shortcut to select desired interpreter is CMD + ,

Answer (score 1):

The answers from @Judge and @gkedge worked for me, but I ran into a few obstacles setting up a project from a github clone with a requirements.txt file.  Here are the steps that worked for me.

First, I had problems with pipenv, so I followed the instructions in the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/74475168/5445739 to install pipenv using python.

Before starting Pycharm, open a terminal and

- clone the project `git clone xyz.git` and `cd xyz`
- set python version `pyenv local 3.11.4`
- activate the pipenv environment `python -m pipenv shell`
- install the packages `pipenv install -r requirements.txt`

Start Pycharm and

- open the project `<path>/xyz`
- select *add an existing python interpreter* and paste the output of the `which python` command; in my case this turns out to be `/home/<user>/.local/share/virtualenvs/<repo>-r0oIFQby/bin/python`

At this point I had a working interpreter along with all the necessary packages. My environment is WSL2 Ubuntu and Pycharm for Windows, version 2022.3.3.