# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently installed python3.10 on my ubuntu system and I believe I made a link from `/usr/bin/python3` to `/usr/bin/python3.10`

If I run `python --version` I get `Python 2.7.17` and if I run `python3 --version` I get `Python 3.10.2`

I believe something I did broke something in my global python / pip.

Whenever I try to use pip globally I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

After googling I thought the issue is that my pip was made using an older version of python I had so I tried to run:

```
sudo apt remove python-pip python3-pip
sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip
```

but even after this I still get the same error with pip.

I do have a virtualenv that I was using with a django project (that uses python 3.10) and if I source into that I am able to use the pip there, but I think this just shows the pip in that venv is properly configured

Result of running `ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep -i`:

```
brick@nextgearserver:/etc/apache2$ ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep -i "pip\|python"
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          26 Mar 26  2018 dh_pypy -> ../share/dh-python/dh_pypy
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root        1056 Apr 16  2018 dh_python2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          29 Mar 26  2018 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          13 Dec  7  2018 lesspipe -> /bin/lesspipe
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          23 Feb 27  2021 pdb2.7 -> ../lib/python2.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          24 Jan 15 13:03 pdb3.10 -> ../lib/python3.10/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          23 Dec  8 16:08 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         292 Apr 30  2021 pip
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         292 Apr 30  2021 pip2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         293 Apr 30  2021 pip3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          31 Oct 25  2018 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          26 Mar 26  2018 pybuild -> ../share/dh-python/pybuild
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           9 Apr 16  2018 python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           9 Apr 16  2018 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     3633000 Feb 27  2021 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          33 Feb 27  2021 python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          16 Apr 16  2018 python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          19 Jan 30 15:07 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     5515256 Jan 15 13:03 python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4526456 Dec  8 16:08 python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          33 Dec  8 16:08 python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4526456 Dec  8 16:08 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          34 Dec  8 16:08 python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          16 Oct 25  2018 python3-config -> python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         384 Feb  5  2018 python3-futurize
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          10 Oct 25  2018 python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          17 Oct 25  2018 python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         388 Feb  5  2018 python3-pasteurize
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         152 Nov 11  2017 python3-pbr
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          16 Apr 16  2018 python-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          29 Apr 16  2018 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root        2971 Feb 27  2021 x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root        3246 Jan 15 13:03 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.10-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          34 Dec  8 16:08 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root        3283 Dec  8 16:08 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          33 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          34 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          33 Apr 16  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu
python2.7-config
```

Comment: Seems like there are still problems with the very recent python release. Therefore I suggest you to use 3.9 instead unless you have a very good reason to use 3.10. Downgrading will probably solve your issue.

Comment: solved here https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5133

Basically, uninstall pipenv from apt and install via pip

Answer (score 53):

In my case, upgrading the following packages worked on Windows 11:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools requests
```

Comment: Worked as charm in Python 3.11 on Ubuntu. The system setuptools are outdated.

Comment: Worked for Python 3.11.5 on macOS Monterey 12.6.8 as well. Thank you!

Comment: Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070063/installing-python-ldap-in-a-virtualenv-on-windows/58235938#58235938 helpful on Windows 11 23H2

Answer (score 47):

I was getting the same error on ubuntu 22.04, This is how I solved it.

remove pipenv if you have installed it using apt

```
sudo apt remove pipenv
```

install pipenv unsing pip

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

activate virtual environment

```
python3 -m pipenv shell
```

install from pipfile

```
pipenv install
```

Comment: You also need to add it to your user path in .bashrc and refresh it: `export PATH= "$HOME/.local/bin:${PATH}"`

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat. Any idea why the original installation through apt caused errors?

Answer (score 43):

**The attribute `MutableMapping` from the module `collections` got moved into `collections.abc`** in `python3.10`.

In your case, `/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py` uses the MutableMapping attribute of collections.

If you can acces the source code, replace all `collections.MutableMapping` with `collections.abc.MutableMapping`.

An example :

```
import collections 
if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 10:

    from collections.abc import MutableMapping
else:
    from collections import MutableMapping
```

Comment: However, this isn't reasonably doable within all 3rd party libraries

Comment: Some 3rd party libraries implement this alternative solution
```
try:
    from collections.abc import Mapping  # novm
except ImportError:
    from collections import Mapping
```

Comment: Python breaking changes within major versions. I love it.

Comment: Why would python make this breaking change?

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure this qualifies as an "answer", but to offer an additional work-around for the case of a library that relies on the existence of `collections.MutableMapping` and hasn't been updated for Python 3.10+, you can place the following code directly before the import of the affected library:

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 10:
    import collections
    setattr(collections, "MutableMapping", collections.abc.MutableMapping)
```

Comment: I've python 3.11 and this was the only solution that worked

Comment: module collections has no attribute abc

Comment: @orrin.pants collections.abc is a [real thing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html). I verified this answer still works in the latest version of python.

Answer (score 10):

There are some Libraries aren't fully compatible with `3.10` to the time of writing this answer

You can downgrade to `3.8` or `3.9` for now and it will work seamlessly

you can find all version for python [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

choose your most suitable version

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. Pip should work out of the box for all Python releases, given it is the defacto Python package manager. Rather, OP is having issues with `/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources` files on the PYTHONPATH. Downgrading would create a separate installation, possibly with new `site_packages`, so this is only a workaround, not really a solution

Answer (score 5):

**For version 3.10 or above –**

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
```

**For version 3.9 or lower –**

```
from collections import MutableMapping
```

If you want this environment completely dynamic then call the below code.

```
import collections 
if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 10:
    from collections.abc import MutableMapping
else:
    from collections import MutableMapping
```

Answer (score 3):

just update requests library version to 2.27.1

use :

```
sudo apt-get install python-requests==2.27.1
```

Comment: How do we do this? I've tried `sudo apt-get install python-requests` but I still have v2.18.4

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python-requests

Comment: Ideally `apt install python-pip`, then use `python -m pip install requests==2.27.1`

Comment: I am on 2.28 .. and python3.10, its like others said, I guess some collections havent been ported over to python 3.10

Answer (score 2):

In my case `pip` was trying to install too old `pyparsing` version from the requirements.txt file. When I changed from `2.0.1` to `2.4.7` everything went fine, so:
`pip install pyparsing==2.4.7`

Comment: For the record, pyparsing became "collections.abc"-aware with version 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

We've bumped into this issue (also disguised as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'`) with this exemplary stacktrace:

```
  File "<..>/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import requests
  File "<..>/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "<..>/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

The solutions posted in a [dedicated blog post](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-urllib3) didn't help. When one actually installs `requests` or even `urllib3` via `pip`/`requirements.txt`, the issue mentioned here pops up with this exemplary stacktrace:

```
  File "<..>/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import requests
  File "<..>/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "<..>/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/requests/cookies.py", line 172, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):

AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

What helped in our case was to pin the `docker` `base` `image` we were using to ensure a python `3.8` install/environment (via an `ubuntu` `package`, in this case `python3-pip`). Having left the base image to `latest` we got a `3.10` `python` environment, which, as others have mentioned, are not compatible with dependencies that are too old and require `3.8`/`3.9`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to make python 3 better and more comatible with itself is to use dynamic loading, for instance the code below fails for some versions of python 3.

```
import tornado.httpclient
```

However the following import works (see code below), it uses the fact that python doesn't normally reload modules and that modules can be altered during runtime. It is an advanced type of load patching method to backport elements that should not have been changed in Python 3 in the official repositories but were for political reasons.

```
import collections.abc
import collections
collections.MutableMapping = collections.abc.MutablesMapping
import tornado.httpclient
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade from `Python3.10` or higher to `Python3.9`.

Comment: Any particular reason why? It's helpful to include reasoning along with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first library that triggers the rest of the others, try
`*pip uninstall urllib3*` or if you need `*sudo pip uninstall urllib3*` and then `*pip uninstall urllib3*` which will update the library.
Even though it's been a year I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.10 has a minimum version of PIP.  When `pip` itself is out of date for python3.10 (raising the `MutableMapping` exception above) and you don't have sudo privileges on the machine in order to install `pip` from `apt` (or, as was likely the case for OP, the apt packages hadn't yet been updated), you can use get-pip.py to upgrade pip.

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py.  The other suggested method `ensurepip` is likely to give the same error as `pip`.

Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) using wget or some other download tool and run `python3.10 get-pip.py` (or whatever python executable you're working with).

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to add another solution for this. I was trying to install 3rd party packages to Python3.10 with pip, and I was getting this error while I was trying. I have been tried every single solution, none of them worked for me except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503329/pip-is-not-working-for-python-3-10-on-ubuntu/69527217#69527217).

Answer (score -1):

To fix:

```
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

exception, install `uplink`:

```
pip install uplink
```

Comment: Any particular reason why? It's helpful to include reasoning along with an answer.