# Error while trying to use Jupyter Notebook with the Python3 kernel. The error message I receive is 'Error loading kernelspec 'python3'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) x64, but I am unable to select a kernel. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter Notebook before, but I still encountered the same error.

```
Error loading kernelspec 'python3'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 309, in get_all_specs
        spec = self._get_kernel_spec_by_name(kname, resource_dir)
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_client/kernelspec.py", line 242, in _get_kernel_spec_by_name
        from ipykernel.kernelspec import RESOURCES, get_kernel_dict
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelspec.py", line 18, in <module>
        from .debugger import _is_debugpy_available
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/debugger.py", line 40, in <module>
        raise e
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/debugger.py", line 23, in <module>
        from debugpy.server import api  # noqa
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debugpy/server/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        import debugpy._vendored.force_pydevd  # noqa
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/force_pydevd.py", line 44, in <module>
        preimport('pydevd', [
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/__init__.py", line 126, in preimport
        import_module(name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "/home/of/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_plugins/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
        __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
        __import__(extant)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
        collections.MutableMapping.register(ParseResults)
    AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter Notebook before, but I still encountered the same error.

```
python --version && python3 --version
Python 2.7.17
Python 3.10.11

jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.13.2
ipykernel        : 6.23.0
ipywidgets       : 8.0.6
jupyter_client   : 8.2.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 2.5.0
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.7.4
nbconvert        : 7.4.0
nbformat         : 5.8.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : 5.4.3
traitlets        : 5.9.0
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter Notebook before, but I still encountered the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `MutableMapping`in `Collections`  was moved in Python 3.10, see: [AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70943244/attributeerror-module-collections-has-no-attribute-mutablemapping)

You can edit the file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py` replacing

```
from collections import MutableMapping
```

with

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
```

or downgrade Python to version 3.9.